# NodeJS - Responding to an infinitely long HTTP request

Tags: node.js, http, server, stream, node-streams

I have a client that sends a HTTP request with infinite data to a Node server.

The server doesn't need the data in the body, so upon reception of a request, it immediately calls `pause()` on the `http.IncomingMessage` stream and proceeds to respond to the request.

But the client never receives the response. Instead, it remains opens and continues to send data forever.

The only way I could make it work was by pausing the stream on the first `'data'` event. But it's not clear to me why.

Server:

```
const http = require('http');

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  console.log('req received');

  req.pause();
  // Swap the line above with this for the client to receive the response:
  // req.on('data', () => req.pause());

  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.end();
});

server.listen(3000, () => console.log('ready'));
```

Client:

```
const http = require('http');
const { Readable } = require('node:stream');

const data = new Readable({
  highWaterMark: 64 * 1024,
  read(n) {
    const buf = Buffer.alloc(n);
    for (let i = 0; i < buf.length; ++i) {
      buf[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    }
    const ret = this.push(buf);
    console.log('sending %d bytes', n, ret ? '' : '(buffer full)');
  }
})

const req = http.request('http://localhost:3000', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
    'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked'
  }
});
req.on('drain', () => console.log('drain'));
req.on('response', res => console.log('response:', res.statusCode, res.statusMessage));
req.on('error', err => console.log('error:', err));
req.on('close', () => console.log('close'));

data.pipe(req);
```

Comment: What is the real world use case here?  You've created a client that sends data forever, but is somehow expecting a response before it finishes sending data?  This is NOT how http requests are expected to work so I'm trying to figure out what you're real use case is so we can perhaps recommend a better way to solve the actual use case.

Comment: Not reading any more data? HTTP headers have been read so I'm assuming the stream is open by now? The idea is to prevent spamming the server with long messages.

Comment: Also besides that, I would like to understand why the client is not working here because I still don't understand what's going on. I initially though I blocked the event loop but since it correctly stops when the server pause on the first chunk, then it might not be the problem. I also have the drain events that indicates the event loop is healthy.

Comment: I would bet that a little research would turn up multiple existing solutions to the overly long incoming request issue.  Probably don't need to solve this one yourself.

Comment: I looked at some codebases and SO questions and I found no solution. body-parser (used by Express) does have max payload size option for the content-type of interests (json, urlencoded), but nothing for the rest. Somehow it is assumed that not listening to the body means that the stream is not flowing nor buffering any more. But how could it be since the HTTP headers have been parsed?